# How to make Saxon XSLT processor report errors to stderr or log4j?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

This is my code:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.setErrorListener(new MyErrorListener());
Transformer trans = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl), sid));
t.setErrorListener(new MyErrorListener());
t.transform(new DOMSource(xml), result);
```

How can I modify this code to make Saxon 9 report errors to stderr? Now it keeps silent no matter what and only throws exceptions of type `TransformerConfigurationException` or `TransformerException` reporting very little to `MyErrorListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about compile time errors or run time errors? For compile time errors (which are more common) you need to set the ErrorListener on the TransformerFactory, not on the transformer.

It would be best if you gave a specific example.

Comment: In the example above I do set the `ErrorListener` on the factory, but I still don't see anything in the log. Yes, I'm talking about compile errors. (BTW, Saxon is awesome, thanks for it!)